# How to create a trigger for an Event Receiver from PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, event-receivers

I want to create a trigger for an Event Receiver (itemupdated) for all items in a list. I know that Ι can just "update" the item through PowerShell, but I can't do that because the list has versioning.

So, is there a way with PowerShell to trigger a specific Event Receiver for all items in a list?

Answer (score 0):

Since an event receiver is attached to a specific **event**, it's only normal that the event needs to occur before the receiver can be executed.

That being said, to execute an ItemUpdating/ed event, obviously your list item should be updated.

On the other hand, if you own the code base yourself, you should

- Separate your code, so that your executing code accepts a ListItem or Dictionary object which would be the same as which your EventReceiver has access to
- Call this executing function from your eventreceiver, **or** call the same function from PowerShell, with the necessary parameters (listitem, dictionary, ...)

> Long story short: no, you cannot trigger the event receiver itself without invoking it's event first.